# create md-autocomplete in angular-material2 with minimal 3 characters then start search the autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, md-autocomplete

we want to create autocomplete that only if user type 3 characters first then autocomplete is suggesting what's inside database.
because the database have around 85,000 objects stored in the server, so the performance is really bad if we have to load all the objects at first.
in angular-material (the first one) there is md-minlength properties in md-autocomplete, there seems no properties like this in angular-material2.
is there any solution for this?

Comment: Did you succeed ? I'm facing the same problem.